# when does iterator gets invalidated

Tags: c++

I am just learning C++ and   came to know that iterators shouldn't be used when container is changed as it might gets invalidated but I just want to know is there anything in C++ standard which says under what situation iterators will get invalidated?

Thanks

Comment: See the related question [**Iterator invalidation rules**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: "I just want to know is there anything in C++ standard which says under what situation iterators will get invalidated?" - It would be quite weird if there was nothing in the Standard about iterator invalidation.

Comment: @H2CO3: there are some very under-specified languages out there, C++ has the distinction of not being one of them ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Well that's true. If everything goes fine, I will enrich the world of under-specified scripting languages with my own little beloved monster within a few weeks... :P Experimental languages FTW!